# Initialize shared NSUserDefaults Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

How do you initialize a NSUserdefaults for a custom appGroup in swift?

```
 var defaults = NSUserDefaults().init(suiteName: "group.mygoup")
```

this give an "init can only refer to self or super" error and doesn't build..

Answer (score 2):

`init` is not used as method in swift. It has its own syntax:

```
var defaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "group.mygoup")
```